# HTML - python bidirectional communication

Tags: python, html

I have the following problem:

The big picture: steering a stepper motor via broswer. The stepper motor is connected to a Fox Board with debian. On the board an apache webserver is running.

I have a HTML website with a form, in which the user enters the parameters for the motor. The submit button starts a python script, which does the communication with the motor. The motor delivers some data to the python script. The script sends this information back to the HTML page in an iframe.

```
web page with form --> 
parameters input by user --> 
submit --> 
python script is started --> 
motor does something --> 
motor sends answer to python script --> 
answer is submited by python to web page in iframe.
```

Works...

One value that is returned by the motor is important, if it exists, I would like to have it in my form in the web page. Not only displayed in an iframe.

My question is: 
a) Is this possible in principle?
b) if yes, how can it be done? Meaning, which are key words to search for? (No clue right now)
c) Is there an alternative.

To a: A self invoking php script could be a solution. But how can I program such a script, that while pushing a submit button, the php is self invoking, the python script gets started, the php waits until python delivers feedbach and finally, the php builds up itself with the data recieved.

I'm on the edge of my own incompetence...

I appreciate any help, suggestions etc... Please just send me in the right direction, Peter

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with AJAX (asynchronous javascript) and python web services, in general. 
The communication would be handled on the client with javascript, and it would invoke your python script (the web service), which would do the work with the motor, and then send the response back to the web page, which would be able to show new readings/state (again, through javascript).

Comment: sooner or later you would meet Javascript when working on the HTML page